# How to Give int-string-int Input as Parameter for Matlab's Matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to have short-hand form about many parameters which I just need to keep fixed in Matlab 2016a because I need them in many places, causing many errors in managing them separately. 
Code where the signal is 15x60x3 in dimensions

```
signal( 1:1 + windowWidth/4, 1:1 + windowWidth,: );
```

Its pseudocode

```
videoParams = 1:1 + windowWidth/4, 1:1 + windowWidth,: ;
signal( videoParams );
```

where you cannot write videoParams as string but should I think write ":" as string and everything else as integers. 
There should be some way to do the pseudocode.

Output of `1:size(signal,3)` is 3 so it gives 1:3. I do not get it how this would replace `:` in the pseudocode.

### Extension for horcler's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995986/54964) as function

```
function videoParams = fix(k, windowWidth)
videoParams = {k:k + windowWidth/4, k:k + windowWidth}; 
end
```

Test call `signal( fix(1,windowWidth){:}, : )` but still unsuccessful giving the error

> ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

so I am not sure if such a function is possible.

---

How can you make such a int-string-int input for the matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish but are [comma separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true#br2js35-10) what you're looking for? You won't be able to use a `:` by itself as it's context dependent, but it can be replaced with `1:size(signal,3)`.

Comment: `fix(1,windowWidth)` returns a cell array. You need the comma-separated list generated by that cell. You can't do it in one line. Instead: `out=fix(1,windowWidth);` `signal(out{:})`. However, if `signal` is a function rather than an array you could modify it to accept a cell array. Also `fix` is the name of a common function show you should probably change that.

Comment: `fix(1,windowWidth){:}` is not valid Matlab (assuming `fix` is a function rather than a cell). Matlab does not support [chaining](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/316855).

Comment: @horchler Yes, you are right. I am just thinking if this could be somehow functionised.

Comment: There's no reason this needs to be one line. It will be optimized by the JIT. One-liners are sometimes convenient, but they can also lead to confusing less maintainable code and less efficient implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished via [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
signal = rand(15,60,3); % Create random data
windowWidth = 2;
videoParams = {1:1+windowWidth/4, 1:1+windowWidth, 1:size(signal,3)};
```

Then use the comma-separated list as such:

```
signal(videoParams{:})
```

which is equivalent to

```
signal(1:1+windowWidth/4, 1:1+windowWidth, 1:size(signal,3))
```

or

```
signal(1:1+windowWidth/4, 1:1+windowWidth, :)
```

The colon operator by itself is shorthand for the entirety of a dimension. However, it is only applicable in a direct context. The following is meaningless (and invalid code) as the enclosing cell has no defined size for its third element:

```
videoParams = {1:1+windowWidth/4, 1:1+windowWidth, :};
```

To work around this, you could of course use:

```
videoParams = {1:1+windowWidth/4, 1:1+windowWidth};
signal(videoParams{:},:)
```

Comment: How can you define videoParams as `{ :, 1:1+windowWidth}` when calling by `videoParams{:}`? Error here. I have environments where I need no dependency between the two variables. If you have the definition, then you cannot use `videoParams{:}`. So I am again what what would be the best way for the definition if you need to use dependency and independency between the two variables.

Comment: @Masi: I don't understand your question. As I indicated in my answer, `{ :, 1:1+windowWidth}`, or `{:}` for that matter, will never work under any circumstances. `:` is meaningless without context. Instead use `videoParams = {1:size(signal,1), 1:1+windowWidth}` and then `signal(videoParams{:},:)`. Yes, this `videoParams` is specific to `signal` and my be meaningless if you want to use it for a completely different size `signal2`. There's no way around this unless you write more complex code or via some horrible and inefficient use of `eval`.